# What does x & 0xfffffe mean?

Tags: android, renderscript, yuv, rgba

in a custom YUV to RGBA Renderscript, I have found the following line which I could not understand:

```
int baseUYIndex = numTotalPixels + (y >> 1) * wIn + (x & 0xfffffe);
```

- `numTotalPixels` is width*height. That is ok.
- `y>>1`. Why they do this ?
- `x & 0xfffffe`. Why they do this ?

The script is from [customYUVToRGBAConverter](https://bitbucket.org/cmaster11/rsbookexamples/src/tip/CameraCaptureExample/app/src/main/rs/customYUVToRGBAConverter.fs).

The reason I ask is because I have first to understand the conversion. In a next step, I want to rotate the Y,U and V components by 90 degrees. I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724927/android-renderscript-rotate-yuv-data-in-renderscript?noredirect=1#comment101891121_57724927) for help, but nobody could help. So, I decided to make it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comment in the linked code, you can see that this routine is intended for a specific kind of YUV: One with chroma subsampling.

> ```
> // YUV 4:2:0 planar image, with 8 bit Y samples, followed by
> // interleaved V/U plane with 8bit 2x2 subsampled chroma samples
> ```

What this means is that there are fewer "color" (U/V) bytes than there are "luminance" (Y) bytes. Specifically, a square consisting of 4 pixels in the original image will only be covered by one "U" and one "V". (It'll have 4 Y's, though.) The U's and V's are interleaved into a separate "plane", which follows the Y plane. [Here](https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV#Semi-planar) is a link that describes the same arrangement in more detail.

Also refer to [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yuv420.svg) picture on Wikimedia (caution: the linked picture is for a slightly different image format, where the U's and V's aren't interleaved).

**CODE ANALYSIS**

The code in question takes an (x,y) coordinate for the original image, and calculates the array offset for the U/V component. (The array offset for the Y component is easy; it's just `x + y * wIn`). Each U/V pair corresponds to a 4-pixel square in the original image; that means each U/V pair covers pixels in 2 adjacent rows.

```
y >> 1
```

This line effectively divides `y` by 2, which gives you the proper row number *for the U/V plane*. Multiply by `wIn` (which is the width of the picture), and you have the byte offset, into the U/V plane, of the start of the U/V row that corresponds to your pixel.

```
x & 0xfffffe
```

This is equivalent to `x - (x % 2)`. In other words, we're making `x` even. This is to calculate the offset, into the U/V row, of the U/V pair. Since each U/V is a two-byte pair, we always want to end up on the first element of the pair: A "U", in this case.

As you can see from this code,

```
uchar _u = rsGetElementAt_uchar(inputAllocation, baseUYIndex);
uchar _v = rsGetElementAt_uchar(inputAllocation, baseUYIndex + 1);
```

the U comes from the byte at the calculated offset; the V, from the next byte.

And there, you have your chrominance.

Comment: ok, thanks for the great explanation. Is there a way to rotate the Y, U and V components by 90 degrees ?

Comment: There should be, I will take a look at your other question and attempt to answer it there. Please accept this answer if you believe it is correct.

Comment: oh, thanks. Yes, I will accept it as answer. I understood the concept much better now.